# How does C# evaluates AND OR expression with no brackets

Tags: c#, .net

not sure if this make sense at all
im trying to understand how C# process the following logic

```
false && true || false
false || true && false
```

basically i'm trying to find out how C# evaluate these expression when there is no parentheses .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler figures it out because the standard specifies [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

That said, if an expression requires you to think for more than a second about what is happening in what sequence... use parentheses to make it clear =)

Comment: As my [poorly worded] answer tries to make clear...I think it is important to point out that c# uses a short circuit '&&' operator. As soon as that initial false is hit, the evaluation stops. Although your answer is a good solution in terms of covering operator precedence, I believe it is important not to forget these details.

Answer (score 13):

`&&` has a higher [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) than `||` so it's evaluated first. Effectively, they're equivalent to:

```
false && true || false  =>  (false && true) || false  =>  false
false || true && false  =>  false || (true && false)  =>  false
```

If you're unsure, *use the parentheses.* They have no real negative impact and anything that makes code more readable is generally a good thing.

Perhaps a better example (so that the results are different) would have been:

```
true && false || false  =>  (true && false) || false  =>  false
true || false && false  =>  true || (false && false)  =>  true
```

Answer (score 3):

[C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) shows operator precedence:

```
false && true || false    =  (false && true) || false        =  false
false || true && false    =  false || (true && false)        =   false
```

`&&` (logical AND) has higher precedence than `||` (logical OR)

**NOTE**: it is good practice (some might say best practice) to always use parentheses to group logical expressions, so that the intention is unambiguous...

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bad example because these evaluate the same whichever precedence you choose :)

Comment: It is a rather bad example, because `((false && true) || false) == (false && (true || false))` and `(false || (true && false)) == ((false || true) && false)`.

Comment: @cHao: you seem to be confusing what happens with actual values, and what is always true.

Comment: i was trying to create my own logic to evaluate the string expression just for fun :) , it'll be much easier with parentheses

Comment: Maybe that's because the example doesn't illustrate that there's a difference that matters.  That's kinda the point.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone said about the operator precedence and the reference tables where you can look that up.  But I'd like to give a hint how to remember it.  If you think of `false` as of `0` and of `true` as of `1` then `&&` is like multiplication and `||` is like addition (they are actually called logical multiplication and logical addition).  The precedence relationship is the same: multiplication is higher then addition.  It works the same way:

```
0 * 0 == 0       |     false && false == false
0 * 1 == 0       |     false && true  == false
1 * 0 == 0       |     true  && false == false
1 * 1 == 1       |     true  && true  == true

0 + 0 == 0       |     false || false == false
0 + 1 == 1       |     false || true  == true
1 + 0 == 1       |     true  || false == true
1 + 1 == 1*      |     true  || true  == true
```

(*) it's actually 2 capped at 1

And normally, when in doubt, use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The operators will be evaluated in order of [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So, basically, `AND` before `OR`s. Your examples are the same as:

```
(false && true) || false
false || (true && false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly... C# uses short circuit operators. So that entire thing is false
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

operator precedence
short circuit evaluation
parenthesis
left to right.

Answer (score -1):

The the AND operator has higher precedence than the OR operator (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). Meaning && is always evaluated first.

Thus `x && y || z` is understood  to  be `(x && y) || z`.

And `a || b && c` is understood to be  `a || (b && c)`.

Comment: There are already *multiple* other answers that contain all of this information that have been around for many years.  This answer is not adding any value.