# Design Pattern or (Literature) Best Practice for C# If-Statement

Tags: c#

I understand if the answer to this question might be subjective, (And I haven't found a similar question) but my question is following:

I've seen code snippets from different sources on the internet/literatures, one of them from my team mates in my projects. Usually some of them go for an approach like...

```
if(a == true && b == false || c == true) {}
```

From my perspective, the if statement could be

1. If a is true AND either b is false OR c is true

   Or (What is likely to be understood by the interpreter, even for me)
2. If a is true AND b is false OR c is true

Due to this conflict of mine having to think properly what statement could be
A) executed or B) originally meant by the Codewriter, I have always used a pattern of my own to make it easier to understand by others, which goes as follows...

```
if(a == true && (b == false || c == true)) {}
```

or

```
if((a == true && b == false) || c == true) {}
```

or (better readability since I think sub-statements inside brackets should be last, not first)

```
if(c == true || (a == true && b == false)) {}
```

Now am I wrong? If I'm right, is there a Design Pattern that supports this kind of syntax? Despite me thinking this is a better approach, Resharper thinks otherwise and finds it redudant.

On the other hand, I want to learn to code better in any way, and if my team mates do it wrong, I should also allow them to have the chance to get better as well in which their code also becomes more readable (if this is true though)

EDIT: It is not about HOW an If-Statement works or how boolean or its precedences work. It is about adding extra brackets to statements where it is not neeeded by default (like comments in codings are not needed), but might be a pattern that (like comments or other design patterns) help in cleaner coding.

Comment: No ambiguity here. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`

Comment: [Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Comment: I personally do not want to remember the precedence, I always use brackets for such an and/or mix - then I am certain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does C# evaluates AND OR expression with no brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455957/how-does-c-sharp-evaluates-and-or-expression-with-no-brackets)

Comment: And I would not check for `a == true`, but just use `a` (but I know, your code is just a sample)

Comment: I don't see something that could be characterized as ambiguous with that expression. Please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator and not the term "short-circuit", if `a` is not `true`, then `a == true` is evaluated as false and whole expression in `if` is evaluated automatically as `false`, no need for checking `b == false || c == true`.

Comment: `I always use brackets` so do I, but I still don't get the premise of the question. What 'pattern' and 'syntax' are we talking about, if there are rules of the language. The statements have different meanings w/ and w/o brackets.

Comment: Lyosha Korogoda
The thing is simply "why put brackets only if it has a different meaning, not when meaning stays the same even without brackets?" -> Possible reasons: It should become more readable, the writer doesn't have to add an additional comment(section) for explaining or simply put writes his intention with the code without giving others the necessarity to double-check his code for possible logical errors.

Comment: I can't believe people upvote this question... Opinion-based duplicate.

Comment: FCin I can't believe you first say "Possible duplicate" and afterwards write as if it is wether possible but just the truth and objective (instead of subjective since it is your opinion).

Please read my Edit I did an hour ago. It is not about how booleans work or how booleans are interpreted or how a series of boolean algorithm is processed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) on MSDN.

With regards to your example, `if (a == true && b == false || c == true)` is evaluated as `if (a is true AND b is false) OR c is true` because **&&** has a higher order of evaluation than **||**.

In terms of readability, I wouldn't explicitly evaluate `== true` or `== false`.

This is less readable and not as clean...

`if (a == true && b == false || c == true) { ... }`

This is more readable and cleaner...

`if(a && !b || c) { ... }`

Resharper complains because you don't need to explicitly specify the order of evaluation if it's exactly the same as it would be without parenthesis, for example:

`if ((a && !b) || c) { ... }` is the same as `if (a && !b || c) { ... }` therefore the extra parenthesis are redundant, and add noise to your code, thus, not as readable.

If you need to explicitly change the order of evaluation, then Resharper shouldn't complain, for example:

`if (a && (!b || c)) { ... }`

With regards to design patterns, nothing leaps to mind with regards to OOP design patterns. This seems more suited to aspects that come from the Functional Programming world, such as pattern matching.

Comment: While knowing the precedence of logical operators is nice, using parentheses liberally is still helpful for junior developers that are still learning and need to understand your logic.

Comment: From your second link "The sections below list the C# operators starting with the highest precedence to the lowest. The operators within each section share the same precedence level." - so there's no need to link to documentation about some other language.

Comment: Like I wrote, I can interpret the code to the point what is meant by it. The question is about readability and possible design pattern to assist a better, probably cleaner coding.

On top of that, I am aware of shortening the boolean statements, it was only as example.

Comment: @HalfSteps with regards to readability and clean coding, in my opinion, and many other developers' `if (a && !b)` is cleaner and more readable than `if (a == true && b == false)`, so apologies if I missed that it was an example. In terms of design patterns, nothing from the OOP world leaps to mind in this respect, though you might find something interesting borrowed from the functional programming world, such as pattern matching.

Comment: @HalfSteps I've updated the answer, hopefully this is more on the mark of what you are asking.

Comment: In my opinion, using (extra) parenthesis explicitly is actually better than assuming every developer who reads the code know the precedence. It is definitely not about being junior developer. People do make mistakes even with or without ReSharper privilege. Parenthesis definitely (re)assures the **intended** logic on top of being more readable (to me at least).

Comment: In my opinion it's better to **learn the language** than to lean on explicit code that adds unnecessary noise. In the same vein, I'm not a fan of Resharper, and I certainly don't think it's a privilege. In my experience with it, it was more of a hindrance than a help. I see the point about parentheses reassuring the intended logic, but it's a more popular developer culture to write unit tests to do that.

Comment: Unforunately it's not the answer I am seeking, and while yes "noise" can be very annoying, but "noise" is on the other hand another subjective thing. So to say "No extra parenthesis -> because it creates noise" is as well to say "Please extra parenthesis -> because better readability". While yes, I seek the second option about readability, but unless there is no design pattern or literature that emphasizes on that, I can't say that my opinion is nothing but subjective, hence why the question.

Comment: To be more precise with my question:

 "why put brackets only if it has a different meaning, not when meaning stays the same even without brackets?" -> Possible reasons: It should become more readable, the writer doesn't have to add an additional comment(section) for explaining or simply put writes his intention with the code without giving others the necessarity to double-check his code for possible logical errors.

But so far there seems to be no design pattern oder literature from the answers to this subject. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinion based question, as you can already see in the comments.

I prefer to keep brackets to make it more visible as I myself sometimes swap the order of && and ||'s evaluation in mind.

```
if((a == true && b == false) || c == true)
vs
if(a == true && b == false || c == true)
```

This gives me a instant impression that a and b must be true or only c is true. If I miss the brackets I need another tought "Was it && before || or vice versa?". Some ppl need it, others dont.

Always try using KISS - keep it simple stupid.
Easiest way is to encapsulate it into a function if the condition is too complex:

```
if(ObjectIsValid(obj))
...
private bool ObjectIsValid(object obj)
{
   return obj.Condition1 == true || (obj.IsSpecial && obj.Specialprop == true) || (obj.SomeEnum == Enumvalue.Value && obj.Specialprop == false) ...;
}
```

The order, if you first check the and or the or condition, may depend on many factors. What if checking the or condition takes the most time? Take the and first. What if the and condition is most unlikely to be met? Place it last.

This heavily depends on the situation you're in. The main point is to keep a style in your team that is understood by everyone and the most readable, working, performant and ACCEPTED BY ALL solution.

**...The best solution isn't always the shortest or most performant.**

And I also support series0ne's "if(a) > if(a == true)".

**EDIT**:
I also want to mention another point that bothers me

```
if(someCondition &&
   someOtherCondition ||
   someThirdCondition)
and
if(someCondition
   && someOtherCondition
   || someThirdCondition)
```

The second one seems *far more* readable to me because i know what is being &&'ed in the same line as the &&. But in this point there are surely also enough ppl to have another opinion on readability.

Comment: Unless I'm missing your point, wrapping the expression into a method might obscure readability. With regards to the OP's question, you'd need a method like `ObjectIsValid(a, b, c) { return a && !b || c; }`, though I think there is perhaps some merit here in that you could unit test the method if the conditional logic was quite complex. Also just for added clarity, you could just `return obj.condition;`

Comment: @series0ne yes, this was just a simplified example. If I check for one condition, I dont encapsulate it. If I check for multiple conditions with some complex dependencies I'd recommend a encapsulation. and perhaps a,b and c are all properties of one class. I modified my answer and added this detail